# Route user after login based on profile parameter

Tags: javascript, meteor

When a user creates a profile they are given a choice between two user choices, meaning that their user profile object will look something like:

```
{
    name: "Jane Doe",
    userType: "user-A"
}
```

What I'd like to do is setup a redirect where, once a user logs in, it will check what type of user they are and redirect them to a page.

If a userType = user-A, they will go to localhost:3000/user-A
If a userType = user-B, they will go to localhost:3000/user-B

I am currently using Iron Router for my routes and accounts-password for accounts

I've tried the following on the client side, but it is printing out null

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit #at-pwd-form': function() {
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
    }
});
```

**Edit 1**

Tried to do this from the server side with the following code as well, but i am getting Iron Router errors:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function () {
  var pathToProfile = "/" + Meteor.user().profile.userType;
  console.log(pathToProfile); // Proof that variable is being saved properly
  Router.go(pathToProfile);
});
```

Error:

```
I20160811-22:58:28.560(-4)? Exception in onLogin callback: TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {
I20160811-22:58:28.560(-4)?     //XXX this assumes no other routers on the parent stack which we should probably fix
I20160811-22:58:28.560(-4)?     router.dispatch(req.url, {
I20160811-22:58:28.560(-4)?       request: req,
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?       response: res
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?     }, next);
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?   } has no method 'go'
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?     at server/main.js:13:10
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?     at runAndHandleExceptions (packages/callback-hook/hook.js:133:1)
I20160811-22:58:28.561(-4)?     at packages/callback-hook/hook.js:140:1
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:167:5
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.each (packages/callback-hook/hook.js:109:1)
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at AccountsServer.Ap._successfulLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:166:21)
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at AccountsServer.Ap._attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:355:10)
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at [object Object].methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:532:21)
I20160811-22:58:28.562(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1704:12)
I20160811-22:58:28.563(-4)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, but on the client-side, you can set the `location` object, whereas on the server-side, you can send a `Location` header with a 302 HTTP response (temporary redirect)

Comment: If you get null, means that no user is logged in. [Meter.userId()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId)

Comment: @Zesky right, thats what I'm trying to figure out.  What I want to do is, once a user has logged in, find out what user type they are and redirect them to a specific page.

Comment: @DavidMoran can you check the Meteor.userId() value immediately after login to confirm login successfully? Is the login screen same as the password form?

Comment: @Zesky you know I think you got me on the right path.  I looked for ways to just get the userId on login and came up with using Meteor.autorun and that did the trick for logging in!  The only issue i have now is that if a user goes back to that page while logged in an error appears, but i think i can work that one out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onSubmitHook` in `AccountsTemplates.configure()`

```
//code goes to lib folder, shared code between client & server
onSubmitHook: function onSubmitHook(error, state) {
    if (!error) {
        if (state === 'signIn') {
            var user = Meteor.user();
            if (user.userType == "user-A") {
                Router.go('/user-A');
            } else {
                Router.go('/user-B');
            }
        }
    }
}
```